# remove one array elements from another array elements in momnet jsusing isSame function

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

i have the flowing two array but i need to remove one array elements from another array elements using moment function

```
let A = [moment('2019-01-17'),moment('2019-01-19')];
let B = [moment('2019-01-17')];

diff = A.filter(x => {
  B.forEach(xx => {
    if (!x.isSame(xx)) {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

expected out put `diff = [moment('2019-01-19')]`
my working live [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/3x743Z6nQbWaYrfV?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to `filter()` should just return a boolean indicating whether that item should be included. You're not returning anything from the callback. You can make the boolean with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which will look in array `B` and see the condition matches all the items. This uses `!some()` which is basically saying, 'it's not the case the some of the items match'. You could also use `every() with the opposite condition.

```js
let A = [moment('2019-01-17'),moment('2019-01-19')];
let B = [moment('2019-01-17')];

diff = A.filter(x => !B.some(xx => x.isSame(xx)));

console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```